# how to remove everything in () while skip col 1 and row 3

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

[image: ![strong text]

I want to remove anything within `()` from col2-3 and skip row 3. what should I do.
Currently I can do the part for the col part but don't know how to skip row 3. Here is my codes:

Sample data can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(Name = c("Patient Number", "Patients with fever", 
"AEDECOD", "DIARRHOEA", "NAUSEA"), Score1 = c("159 (100%)", "159", 
"Total", "131 (82.39%)", "92 (57.86%)"), Score2 = c("3", "3", 
"test2", "2 (66.67%)", "2 (66.67%)"), Score3 = c("3", "3", "test3", 
"2 (66.67%)", "1 (33.33%)")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The output that I want is sth looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** *I missed the "skip row 3" part of the question - in part because it is still in your example output so it's not clear what you mean. I've added a filter at the end of the question*.

You have the right idea using `mutate(across())`. You can use `gsub` to replace "spaces followed by anything in parentheses":

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Score"), ~gsub("\\s+\\(.*?\\)", "", .x)))
```

Result. Note that the columns are type character as you have mixed text + numbers. You might want to `mutate` using `as.numeric()` after removing row 3.

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Name                Score1 Score2 Score3
  <chr>               <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Patient Number      159    3      3     
2 Patients with fever 159    3      3     
3 AEDECOD             Total  test2  test3 
4 DIARRHOEA           131    2      2     
5 NAUSEA              92     2      1
```

One way to remove row 3 is to add a `filter`. Another way is to use `slice(-3)`.

After that you can mutate the numbers to type numeric.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Score"), ~gsub("\\s+\\(.*?\\)", "", .x))) %>%
  # or slice(-3) instead of next line %>%
  filter(Name != "AEDECOD") %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Score"), ~as.numeric(.x)))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Name                Score1 Score2 Score3
  <chr>                <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Patient Number         159      3      3
2 Patients with fever    159      3      3
3 DIARRHOEA              131      2      2
4 NAUSEA                  92      2      1
```